# MySQL error: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" - beginner help

Tags: php, mysql

basically, php & MySQL being used. I am a beginner.

What I am trying to do is registering a user to my database, so storing the form input to my users_tb.

get this error when I try inserting the values into the form:

"Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

I thought it was because I wasn't inserting the user_id value (which is auto increment), so I tried inserting '' in my query for the user_id, but still no luck.

here is the query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users_tb (user_id, user_status, user_gender, user_firstname, user_surname, student_number,
    user_email, user_dob, user_name, user_pass) 
    VALUES('','$status','$gender','$firstname','$surname','$hnumber','$dob','$username','$password')";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_close();
```

whether that helps. If you need any other code just say.

just to make sure though, the inserts don't have to be in same order the fields are in the table do they?

many thanks,

Comment: Take note that this way of constructing a query is very dangerous. Think for a moment what would happen if somebody with the name `'); DROP TABLE users_tb; --` would come along... It's good practice to wrap all the variables in `mysql_real_escape_string()` calls: `$query = "INSERT INTO users_tb (user_id, user_status ....) VALUES('', '". mysql_real_escape_string($status) ."', '". mysql_real_escape_string($gender) ."', ...)";`

Comment: @Rodin, hopefully he's cleaning the variables before the query ;)

Comment: @Rodin DROP TABLE users_tb will cause an error and nothing more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're missing one value.

For queries this long with so many columns (and if you're inserting just one row), I'd suggest using the following INSERT syntax, which is much easier to read and less likely to cause problems.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users_tb SET
          user_status    = '". mysql_real_escape_string($status) ."',
          user_gender    = '". mysql_real_escape_string($gender) ."',
          user_firstname = '". mysql_real_escape_string($firstname) ."',
          user_surname   = '". mysql_real_escape_string($surname) ."',
          student_number = '". mysql_real_escape_string($hnumber) ."',
          user_email     = '". mysql_real_escape_string($email) ."',
          user_dob       = '". mysql_real_escape_string($dob) ."',
          user_name      = '". mysql_real_escape_string($username) ."',
          user_pass      = '". mysql_real_escape_string($password) ."'";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();
```

Comment: don't you find it quite boring to type all that mess?

Comment: No. I find it much simpler to read. And for me that's a very important part of code.

Comment: It's sad you'd commit a suicide over a piece of code. I sometimes used similar things with loops etc as you proposed but usually this simple list-like query works better in terms of readability and maintainability and also gives me better control over the input if I need to modify some fields in a different way etc.

Comment: what maintainability you are talking about? When it happens to add some fields to table, I have to add it's names to the list. And no mistakes caused by forgetting to set it in some place. Because there is only one place to set. There are no repetitions in my code, and thus it's considered as better maintainable than yours. And reusable too

Comment: Lesser code doesn't have to equal better code. And just because in this case the values are all treated the same way (escaped POST values) doesn't mean it's always like that, often different functions are applied on different values from different sources. Sure, you could split it up into more different loops but in the end it's probably gonna be even more messy. But maybe our scenarios just differ that much.

Comment: @AnandSomasekhar Not sure what you're asking..? Check SQL documentation.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a value for `user_email`.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users_tb
          (
              user_status,
              user_gender,
              user_firstname,
              user_surname,
              student_number,
              user_email,
              user_dob,
              user_name,
              user_pass
          ) 
          VALUES
          (
              '$status', 
              '$gender',
              '$firstname',
              '$surname',
              '$hnumber',
              '$email',    -- <--- you forgot this!
              '$dob',
              '$username',
              '$password'
          )";
```

And just a reminder: you should escape the values using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) if you are not already doing so.

Comment: your edit missed the `user_id` column and it's associated value from the original question.

Comment: @Ken White: I don't think it's needed. He said that `user_id` is an auto-increment column so there's no need to insert any value into it - a value will be generated by the database automatically.

Comment: I saw that, but your post didn't address your removing it; that's what I was pointing out so the OP noticed the difference as well. I should have made my comment more clear, along the lines of "your edit also removed the `user_id` from both the columns and values lists, because they weren't needed."

Answer (score 2):

Mark Byers answered the problem part, but didn't address this question:

> just to make sure though, the inserts don't have to be in same order the fields are in the table do they?

No, they don't have to be in the same order as the columns in the table, but your columns list and your values list have to match both in count and in data type. The problem you have is the one Mark spotted; you're missing a value for `user_email`, which means the `dob` value is trying to go in that column instead. MySQL is seeing that there aren't enough values for the columns you listed, and reporting the error back to you.

`Column count doesn't match value count` is actually a pretty clear message, which is unusual for database engines. :)

Comment: @Mark: :) I gave you a +1 for covering the other part.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple function to create a query out of $_POST array and list of allowed fields:

```
function dbSet($fields) {
  $set='';
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
      $set.="`$field`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field])."', ";
    }
  }
  return substr($set, 0, -2); 
}
```

used like this

```
$table  = "users_tb";
$fields = explode(" ","user_status user_gender user_firstname user_surname student_number user_email user_dob user_name user_pass");
$query  = "INSERT INTO $table SET ".dbSet($fields);
mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query);
```

of course it's assuming that HTML form field names match SQL table field names, which is very handy consideration

Answer (score 0):

you've got 10 fields you want to insert, but you're providing only 9 values

Comment: Close. There are 10 columns, but 9 values. (As Mark Byers said, it's `user_email`.)

Answer (score 0):

You list 10 columns but you only have 9 values.

Comment: Close, but no cigar. See my comment to freddy K. above. :)

Comment: guys thanks. Must have been a long day and I was being blind. I have validated the form input already, but I had intended on using that function, I was just trying to get the query to work, without then jumping ahead of myself. thanks again.