# Strange out of bounds exception when trying to read cell

Tags: java, jxl

I've been trying to read an excel sheet and insert data from cells into a program. I am successful to a point, but when I try and get the data from cells in position 4 and onwards, I get an out of bounds exception. No idea why this would be, as I can call positions 0,1,2 and 3 just fine. Here is my code.

```
public void readExcel(File file) {

try {

//Workbook newBook = new Workbook();
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
WritableWorkbook workbookOutput = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"));
// Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(“Res.xls”));
WritableSheet sheetOutput = workbookOutput.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);


sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
boolean isnotnull = true;
int i = 0;
while(isnotnull){

    //Cell a1 = sheet.getCell(0, 2);
try{
    Cell a2 = sheet.getCell(0, i);
    Cell a3 = sheet.getCell(1, i);
    Cell a4 = sheet.getCell(2, i);
    stringa1 = a2.getContents();
    stringa2 = a3.getContents();
    stringa3 = a4.getContents();

    char c = stringa2.charAt(0);
    char d = stringa2.charAt(1);

    if(Character.isDigit(c) || Character.isDigit(d)){
        System.out.println("found one");
        stringa1 = stringa1 + "" + stringa2;
        stringa2 = stringa3;
        Cell a5 = sheet.getCell(3, i);
        try{
            Cell a10 = sheet.getCell(4, i);
           // System.out.print("Cell" + a6.getContents());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        stringa4 = a5.getContents();
        stringa3 = stringa4;
      //  checkCells(1, i);

    }
    Label label = new Label(0, i, stringa1);
    Label label2 = new Label(1, i, stringa2);
    Label label3 = new Label(2, i, stringa3);
    sheetOutput.addCell(label);
    sheetOutput.addCell(label2);
    sheetOutput.addCell(label3);
    i++;
    System.out.println(stringa1 + " |||||||||||| " + stringa2 + " |||||||| " + stringa3 + " " + i);
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
    isnotnull = false;
}

}

workbookOutput.write(); 
try{
workbookOutput.close();
}catch(Exception r){
    System.out.println(r);
}
System.out.println(stringa1);

workbook.close();

} catch (BiffException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {

   e.printStackTrace();

}

}`enter code here`
```

Comment: I think [this is a similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953363/writing-excel-data-to-database-in-java/14953416#14953416). If a row ends after say 4 cells, the fifth cell is not present in the (array backed!) list containing the cells of the rows. So you are trying to get the 5th element in a 4 long array: OutOfBounds exception. You always have to test if the list is long enough to get that element, before attempting to get it...

Comment: Is there nothing I can do to get this element?

Answer (score 0):

This cell simply doesn't exist in a spreadsheet. It seems that `createSheet` method creates only few first Cells.

Comment: Is there any way I can create other cells? Perhaps a different JAR or something? I really need to access the information in the cells.

Comment: If the cell _is not there_, what do you  want to read from it?

Comment: Is this because my code is causing it to not be there? It exists in the actually spreadsheet...

Comment: Even if you can see it in Excel - it doesn't mean the cell exists.
You should use:
`sheet.getRow( rowNumber ).createCell( columnNumber );`